# vk API [15] Access denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Использую библиотеку `vk_api`

В сообществе сформировал ключ доступа вида 6478d5d10afd6a8*************4d331053206551*********a61e600e4be******

```
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='6478d5d10afd6a8*************4d331053206551*********a61e600e4be******', scope='messages')
vk = vk_session.get_api()
```

Далее с запроса достаю данные:

```
peer_id = data['object']['peer_id']
message_id = data['object']['conversation_message_id']
```

И делаю запрос на редактирование сообщения

```
return vk.messages.edit(peer_id=peer_id, message_id=message_id, message="some text")
```

Вся проблема в том что при вызове messages.edit вк возвращает ошибку - [15] Access denied

Почему? не понимаю, ведь в документации было описано следующее:

> Получить ключ доступа сообщества можно одним из этих способов:
>   В интерфейсе настроек сообщества. Для этого достаточно открыть раздел «Управление сообществом» («Управление страницей», если у Вас публичная страница), выбрать вкладку «Работа с API» и нажать «Создать ключ доступа».

А в описании самого [метода](https://vk.com/dev/messages.edit) требовалось лишь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ключ есть, [права доступа](https://vk.com/dev/permissions) я также получил указывая `scope='messages'`

Помогите пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка? 
Ниже предоставлю весь код и примры запросов

```
 @csrf_exempt
 def vk(request):
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='6478d5d10afd6a8*************4d331053206551*********a61e600e4be******', scope='messages')
    vk = vk_session.get_api()

try:
    data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    print(data)
    if data['type'] == 'message_new' and data['secret'] == 'wqdh8q7wdh7qwu':
        try:
            user_id = data['object']['from_id']
            peer_id = data['object']['peer_id']
            message_id = data['object']['conversation_message_id']
            text = data['object']['text']
            try:
                payload = data['object']['payload'].replace('"', '')
            except KeyError:
                payload = ""
        except AttributeError:
            pass
    else:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()

    def edit_message(peer_id, message_id, message, keyboard=None):
        return vk.messages.edit(peer_id=user_id, message_id=message_id, message=message, keyboard=keyboard)

    def send_message(user_id, message, keyboard=None):
        return vk.messages.send(user_id=user_id, message=message, keyboard=keyboard)

    if_exist = BotUser.objects.filter(vk_chat_id=user_id).count()
    if if_exist != 0:
        user = BotUser.objects.get(vk_chat_id=user_id)

    if text == 'PING':
        user.step = 'edit'
        user.save()
        keyboard = VkKeyboard()
        keyboard.add_button(label='q', payload="a")
        vk.messages.send(user_id=user_id, message='PONG', keyboard=keyboard.get_keyboard())
        return HttpResponse('OK')

    if user.step == 'edit' and text:
        edit_message(peer_id, message_id, "kekekekeke")
        return HttpResponse('OK')
```

Прим исходящего запроса на сервер:

```
{'type': 'message_new', 'object': {'date': 1534675493, 'from_id': 370459341, 'id': 762, 'out': 0, 'peer_id': 370459341, 'text': 'qwerty', 'conversation_message_id': 763, 'fwd_messages': [], 'important': False, 'random_id': 0, 'attachments': [], 'is_hidden': False}, 'group_id': 170000027, 'secret': 'jjsdjkcsjkcsjkcsjk'}
```

Comment: Почему вы используете `data['object']['conversation_message_id']`, а не `data['object']['id']`?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie я указывал оба варианта, к сожалению ошибка не изменялась. Код к тому моменту как я понял не доходит еще, т.к на старте отказывает в доступе

Answer (score 0):

```
a = vk.messages.send(
  user_id=event.user_id,
  message='123',
  random_id=get_random_id(),
  keyboard=check_animations_kb.get_keyboard()
)  
print(a)
print(event.message_id)
                                    
vk.messages.edit(
  peer_id=event.user_id,
  message='456',
  message_id=(event.message_id + 1),
  keyboard=check_animations_kb.get_keyboard()
)
```

Сам с такой проблемой столкнулся, по итогу эта ошибка связана с тем что ВЫ и Я РЕДАКТИРУЕМ СООБЩЕНИЕ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ, А НЕ БОТА. Вам нужно прибавлять к вашему message_id 1 единицу и это будет сообщение отправленное ботом.
Вот верный ответ:

```
vk.messages.edit(
  peer_id=event.user_id,
  message='456',
  message_id=(event.message_id + 1),
  keyboard=check_animations_kb.get_keyboard()
)
```